# $A=\{(x,y):y=0,x\in<0,1>\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ closed? open? bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> $$A=\{(x,y):y=0,x\in<0,1>\}$$  $<,>$ stands for interval and not an inner product

$\{B_{n}\}=(1-\frac{1}{n},0)\longrightarrow_{n\to\infty}(1,0)$

That is $\{B_{n}\}\in A$ but the limit point $(1,0)\not\in A$ and therefore $A$ is not closed.

On the other hand the ball of $B<(0.5,0),r>\not\subseteq A$ for any $r>0$ and therefore $A$ is not open

$||(x-y)-(x_{0},y_{0})||=\sqrt{(x-x_{0})^2+(y-y_{0})^2}$ Because $A$ is defined such that $y=0$ for all $a\in A$ $=\sqrt{(x-x_{0})^2}=|x-x_{0}|<1$

So for every $a\in A$ $||a-a_{0}||<1$ and therefore $A$ is bounded

Is there a shorter way to prove the above? in general can we say that every open interval which is in a lower dimension from the whole space is not open and not closed? for example: $(x,y,z):-1<x<1,-1<y<1,-1<z<1$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$?

Comment: As you are using both the ordered pair (0,1) *and* the open interval (0,1) in the same proof with the exact same notation.... I'd suggest using different notation.  maybe ]0,1[ for the interval and/or <0,1> for the pair....

Comment: That's pretty darned short.  I don't see why you'd want shorter. In fact I was going to suggest you prove "B((0.5,0),r)⊈A" rather than take it for granted.  Yes, you can so an open rectangle in a lower dimension is not open or closed in a higher dimension by the exact proof you gave.  Just more variable fewer specifics.

Comment: maybe now you should specify what the notation < 0, 1 > means.  I don't think it is standard for intervals.

Comment: @fleablood So $r=1$ is not enough?

Comment: No, it's *definitely* enough.  I was being fast and dirty.  Maybe I'll delete my comment as... it's not really helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all correct. The intuition behind closed and open ( at least in $dim E < +\infty$) is linked to inequalities ($x\le a$) for closed interval and strict inequality ($x<b$) for open intervals.

Therefore is you stumble upon an interval that's defined with both type of inequality (wich is the case here), chances are it's neither closed or open.

As for the bounded part, the most general way to prove it is to include the interval inside a ball.

In you example you got $A \subset B(0,1)$ given that $\mathbb{R}^2$ got the euclidian "norme" (I'm not sure of the english word, I'm referring to the linear forms we use to measure spaces).

Also as a side note, please try and use good formatting for the intervals, we can deduce your notation from what you wrote but it would be much nicer if it was the good form from the start =)

EDIT : As per your last question, your result is true because intuitively, if one coordinate is not bounded, the whole interval isn't either (note that this is dependant of the norm you're using).

Comment: And what about the case of an interval with infinity? for example $y=x^2$ in $R^2$?

Comment: Let set $A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 : y=x^2 \}$.
You can easily prove it is not bounded.
Now I think the easiest way to prove it is closed it to have a look at $C_A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 : y\ne x^2 \}$ it's complementary and prove it's open (ie for each element of $C_A$ you can find a ball around it $\subset C_A$)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** for $A$ not open.
with
$$C_n=(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{n})$$

we have

$$\forall n>0 \;\;  C_n \notin A$$

but

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}C_n=(\frac{1}{2},0)\in A$$

thus, $A$ is not open cause its complement is not closed.

Comment: I may missing something out, but why $\forall n>0 \;\;  C_n \notin A$? for $n>2$ $C_{n}\in A$

Comment: Look at the second coordinate of $C_n = ({1\over 2},{1\over n})$.

$\forall n>0, {1\over n}>0$ so $\forall n>0, C_n \notin A$

Comment: @AbdallahHammam in your argument you showed that there is a squance that all of its elements and also its limit point is not contained in the set?

Comment: @gbox the limit IS in the set.

Comment: @AbdallahHammam Sorry, ok so the complement is not and therefore the set in not open as you said, is it a definition\ ?

Comment: @gbox A set is open if its complement is closed.

Comment: The rule is :
Let $A$ and $C_A$ be two complementary intervals in a vectorial space $E$ ($A+C_A = E$).
Then the following is true :
$A$ closed $\Leftrightarrow$ $C_A$ open

The very important thing to get here is "$A$ not closed" **does not** mean "$A$ open".

So proving $C_A$ not closed only proves $A$ not open.

Comment: @Furrane Yes.$C_A$ not closed implies $A$ not open.

Comment: To put it in a not formal way, we can conclude on the complement (closed/open) from the set itself, but it can not conclude on the set itself from its being not open or not closed